# Simple Table CSS border issue

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a issue with a table. I want just a border-bottom to be set and I wanted to have no gaps in between the td's, my css looks like this:

```
#questions td
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid thin black;
}
```

questions is the id of my table. I've tried setting the border bottom of the tr but this seems to do nothing (in Chrome and Firefox at least). My table looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }
```

This is the CSS replacement for the `cellspacing` attribute.